# Why do I get an object reference error when i try to call my method?

Tags: c#, winforms

For this peice of code I get an error when i try to call `Square.EffectOnPlayer(player);`
The error says an object reference is required, Why wont it accept `player`?

```
public void  Move(int numberOfSquares, Player player) {
    int current_pos;
    int new_pos;

    current_pos = Square.GetSquarenumber(location);
    new_pos = numberOfSquares + current_pos;

    location = Board.GetGameBoardSquare(new_pos);

    Square.EffectOnPlayer(player);
}
```

will be refreshing on page to give more information if needed.

EDIT
this is the square class library which the method refers to (variables left out):

```
public class Win_Square : Square
{
    public Win_Square(string n,int nu)

    {
        Name = n;
        number = nu;
    }

    public override void EffectOnPlayer(Player who)
    {
        who.Add(add);
    }
}

public class Lose_Square : Square
{
    public Lose_Square(string n,int nu)
    {
        Name = n;
        number = nu;
    }

    public override void EffectOnPlayer(Player who)
    {
        who.Deduct(deduct);
    }  
}

public class Chance_Square : Square
{
    public Chance_Square(string n,int nu)
    {
        Name = n;
        number = nu;
    }

    public override void EffectOnPlayer(Player who)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        if (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0)
            who.Deduct(one_hundred);
        else
            who.Add(one_hundred);
    }
}

public static int GetSquarenumber(Square square)
{
    int n = 0;
    string name;
    name = square.Name;

    if (name == "Finish")
    {
        n = 55;
    }
    if (name == "Start")
    {
        n = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        n = Int32.Parse(name);
    }
    return n;
}

public virtual void EffectOnPlayer(Player who) { }

}
```

Comment: Is your Square variable a class or an object instance? Can you show us the definition of `Square` and the `EffectOnPlayer` method?

Comment: Debug your code (debugging is the most basic and vital skill to any programmer) and tell us what Square is.

Comment: Square is probably not static.

Comment: If the problem is caused by Square not being static, is there a way around this without making Square static?

Comment: @user2396303 Yeah, if you don't want to make something static, then you need to keep a reference somewhere. From making a singleton, to keeping an array of references, to passing parameters. Without knowing what your application does and seeing it's complete code it's a shot in the dark as to how you should proceed.

Comment: You assign the location variable after you use it in the Square.GetSquarenumber() call. Make sure that the location variable isn't null and that it is assigned before calling Square.GetSquarenumber().

Answer (score 3):

```
public override void EffectOnPlayer(Player who)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    if (rand.Next(0, 2) == 0)
        who.Deduct(one_hundred);
    else
        who.Add(one_hundred);
}
```

This function is not Static while the others are so calling EffectOnPlayer without a reference to an instance of Square class will result in an error. So you either need a reference to the Square instance or make it static.

If you just give the Move function a refences to a square instance everything should be ok.

```
public void  Move(int numberOfSquares, Player player, Square square)
{
     square.EffectOnPlayer(player);
     ...
}
```

Comment: But when I want to call move do I need to put someone in `square`?

Comment: I'm guessing some here but I guess you want something to happen to the player depending on what square the player stand on. So you need to someway get the square instance the player is currently standing on and use that instance to call EffectOnPlayer on. So do you have some form of data structure that is traversed with different square in it? If so make a function that get the current square instance and use it.